# MDX Invalid token, Line 3, Offset 74,

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I'm quite new to MDX but learning by the power of Google!

I have the below statement:

```
WITH MEMBER _X AS
Sum ( ( [Time].[Week].CurrentMember:[Time].[Week].CurrentMember.Lag ( [Measures].[Normalised Weight Calculation Weeks].Value - 1 ) , 
[Market].[Shop].CurrentMember ) , [Measures].[Stock Out Cleansed Sales] ) 
SELECT
 _X
ON 0,
NON EMPTY(
[Product].[Concept Group].[Concept Group],
[Market].[Shop].[Shop],
[Time].[Week].[Week]
) ON 1 
FROM CompanyName
```

However, I keep receiving the below error - which token is actually invalid though?

```
Query (3, 74) Parser: The following syntax error occurred during parsing: Invalid token, Line 3, Offset 74,  .
```

Thanks.

Comment: your question lacks description. You need to explain what are you trying to achive with this query. Specificly you should explain why are you passing             
"[Measures].[Normalised Weight Calculation Weeks].Value - 1" to the lag function.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone was interested it was just white space at the end of the statement.  Anyway, working now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (Line 2, Offset 3). I was puzzled as to why it failed - I'd copied a similar query that worked and used Word to find and replaced table/column names.
It turned out that was the problem: Word had swapped the straight quotes (') for curly ones (‘ ’). The first one occurred on the 2nd line, in the 3rd position.